# Derivative of 1-norm

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

> Let $A\in \mathcal{R}^{n\times n} $ be a real matrix and $x_0,x\in \mathcal{R}^{n\times 1} $.
>   What is the gradient of the following function at $x$ assuming $Ax \neq x_0$:
>   $\|Ax-x_0\|_1$

Comment: Note correct notation $n\times n$, not $nxn$.  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

You are probably aware of the fact that the mapping is not differentiable. However, it is *convex* and hence, basically all the information one wants to know from some kind of derivative is encoded in the *[subgradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative#The_subgradient)*. In this case you have
$$
\partial(\|Ax-x_0\|_1) = A^T\partial\|Ax-x_0\|_1.
$$
In general, the subgradient is multivalued. In case $(Ax_0)_k\neq x_k$ for all $k$, then the subgradient is single-valued and is
$$
\partial(\|Ax-x_0\|_1) = A^T\mathrm{sign}(Ax-x_0).
$$
However, as soon as $Ax$ and $x_0$ coincide in one component, the subgradient will be multivalued. However, using the same formula as the last one will still give you one particular subgradient.

Answer (score 1):

Solving in coordinates, one gets the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#p-norm) $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \|x\|_p = \frac{x_k |x_k|^{p-2}}{\|x\|_{p}^{p-1}}$. For $p=1$ and with obvious existence conditions $x_i \ne 0$ we can write 
$\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}$

$$D\| x\|_1 = (\sgn(x_1), \ldots, \sgn(x_n))=sgn(x)$$

$$D\| Ax-b\|_1 = \sgn(Ax-b)A$$
where in the last expression we used the chain rule.